# How can I edit this one to expand onmouseenter and collapse onmouseleave

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am using a wordpress plugin that I have managed to change it a bit but I was thinking of making it expand onmouseenter and collapse onmouseleave but I am not sure how to edit it.

```
    $(document).on("click", ".woocommerce.widget_product_categories .product-categories li.cat-parent > .cat-menu-close", function(e) {
var $catParent = $(this).closest('li.cat-parent');
var state = 'opened'


$catParent.toggleClass(state);


$(this).nextAll('ul.children:first').slideToggle(state);
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind a function to the div:

```
$( 'div you want to hover selector' )
  .mouseover(function() {
      $catParent.toggleClass(state);
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
      $catParent.toggleClass(state);
  });
```

[jQuery Mouseover](https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)

Comment: when I try to add your code to the js it either doesn't show the dropdown at all or it does show the dropdown but doesn't move. I am not sure if I get it.

Comment: I mean I edited th code like this
 `$(document)
 .mouseover(".woocommerce.widget_product_categories .product-categories li.cat-parent > .cat-menu-close", function(e) {
      var $catParent = $(this).closest('li.cat-parent');
      var state = 'opened'
      $catParent.toggleClass(state);
      $(this).nextAll('ul.children:first').slideToggle(state);
  })
    .mouseout(".woocommerce.widget_product_categories .product-categories li.cat-parent > .cat-menu-close", function(e) {
      var $catParent = $(this).closest('li.cat-parent');
      $catParent.toggleClass(state);
  });`
@KGreene

Comment: it was actually cashed for some reason and didn't work. I didn't use .mouseover and .mouseout but actually .onmouseenter and .onmouseleave.